# List item returning weird title

Tags: list

I am using the object model to loop through the items in the built in "Task" list.  For some reason when I get the value for the "Title" field for each item it returns values like `1_.000`, `2_.000` etc. instead of returning the title that is displayed by the default view.

Do I need to do something special to get the actual title rather than these strange values?

P.S. I checked which columns are being displayed in the default view and there are three versions of Title in there: "Title", "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" and  "Title (linked to item) ".  I tried using each one but still get the weird values.

Comment: Can you list the code?  Does it behave the same against other list types?

Comment: It just happens for the `Task` list.  I will post some code up later today.

Comment: This isn't in a meeting workspace, is it?

Comment: Your days are looong... ;)

Comment: did you ever find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [SPListItem.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.title.aspx)?

You might want to just try:

```
SPListItem item; // get the item from somewhere
string title = item["Title"].ToString();
```

Comment: No i'm not using `SPLIstItem.Title`.  I am using the method you suggested.

Comment: We need your code! :) Just tried on my Tasks list, and I'm getting right title value from both `item.Title` and `item["Title"].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with a OOB Task list and it worked fine with the code below.

```
public static void TestOneFuncOne()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://siteurl"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
            foreach (SPItem item in items)
            {
                String title = item["Title"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have you read about how SharePoint the reference to version URL [SPListItemVersion.Url Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion.url.aspx)?